# Calculate the sum of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I have created an array using the following JavaScript:

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfPeriodsCost; i++) {
    esclatedPrice *= (1 + annualElecIncrease)
    rateArray.push(esclatedPrice);
    annualCostA = consumptionA * rateArray[i]
    console.log("annualCostA= " + annualCostA);
}
```

For context:

```
var numOfPeriodsCost = 10;
var annualElecIncrease = 0.1;
var consumptionA = 520;
```

The console logs the following for annualCostA:

[image]

How would I take this one step further and calculate the sum of the array?

Thanks

Comment: What is the initial value of `esclatedPrice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you just need to add a variable `sum` that will add the value of `annualCostA` in each iteration like so:

```
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numOfPeriodsCost; i++) {
    esclatedPrice *= (1 + annualElecIncrease)
    rateArray.push(esclatedPrice);
    annualCostA = consumptionA * rateArray[i]
    sum += annualCostA // add the annualCostA value in each iteration 
    console.log("annualCostA= " + annualCostA);
}
console.log(sum); //total sum
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for my situation. Thanks so much, it was awesome to learn about this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var sumOfRateArray = rateArray.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
```

Code:

```js
const rateArray = [12.100000000000001,13.310000000000002,14.641000000000004,16.105100000000004,17.715610000000005,19.487171000000007,21.43588810000001,23.579476910000015,25.937424601000018];
const sumOfRateArray = rateArray.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);

console.log(sumOfRateArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a sum variable before the loop `let sum=0;`

Add the element you want to sum inside the loop `sum+= your_element;`

Print the result `console.log("Sum= "+sum);`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on your `rateArray` variable after the loop:

```js
var rateArray = [
    936,
    1029.6,
    1132.56
];

var arraySum = rateArray.reduce((total, e) => total + e);

console.log(arraySum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numOfPeriodsCost = 10;
var annualElecIncrease = 0.1;
var consumptionA = 520;

let sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numOfPeriodsCost; i++) {
  esclatedPrice *= (1 + annualElecIncrease);
  rateArray.push(esclatedPrice);
  annualCostA = consumptionA * rateArray[i]
  console.log("annualCostA= " + annualCostA);
  sum += annualCostA;
}

console.log('sum', sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the `forEach` approach:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let sum = 0;
numbers.forEach((item, index)=>{sum= sum + item;});
document.write("Sum: " + sum);
```

Test: [link](http://tpcg.io/OqxCSQ)

Doc: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your yearly calculation, should it be `consumption + (years*increase*consumption)`?

You can map an array of 0-numOfPeriodsCost to yearly costs and reduce that to an array containing costs for that year and total until that year. Then map those values into objects containing total and year:

```js
const numOfPeriodsCost = 10;
const annualElecIncrease = 0.1;
const consumptionA = 520;

console.log(
  [...new Array(numOfPeriodsCost)]
    .map(
      (_, period) =>
        consumptionA +
        period * annualElecIncrease * consumptionA,
    )
    .reduce(
      ([sum, result], item) => [
        sum + item,
        result.concat([[sum + item, item]]),
      ],
      [0, []],
    )[1]
    .map(([total, year]) => ({ total, year })),
);
```